# Android Toolbar Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, toolbar, android-tabs, android-toolbar

I would like to implement tabs under my toolbar.
With the actionbar you did it with

> actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)

but now i searched everywhere and can't find it for the toolbar.

I just want a slideview with 3 tabs.
It would be nice if someone can help me with it.

[I mean something simple like this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Z6EdTqIEALU/T9sNVvs8XgI/AAAAAAAABY8/Cw8PnPTpTVI/s1600/action_bar_pattern_considerations.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ViewPager` for the tab contents, and your choice of tabbed indicator for the tabs:

- `PagerTabStrip`
- `TabPageIndicator` from [the ViewPagerIndicator library](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)
- [`PagerSlidingTabStrip`](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)
- any of [the other tab implementations for `ViewPager`](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/111)

Or, use `FragmentTabHost`, if you prefer.

The old action bar tabs are deprecated and specifically are not a part of `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 1):

This flexible library work with Toolbar
https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs

Comment: They look like a nice replacement for the ViewPagerIndicator library. Which is kind of outdated. I give it a try.